# Pass parameters from launch file to python script in Unit Test(Rostest)

Tags: python-2.7, unit-testing, integration-testing, ros

I am working on implementing a Python Unit test(rostest) whereby i can pass parameters from a roslaunch file to my python generic script for testing. However my test is failing, and normally it should pass. I will paste my code here and also will be glad to get some feedback on why this is happening.

The final goal is to have one generic python template that many launch files can use to do integration test

my script reading parameters from the roslaunch file:

```
class itn_rtest_group1template(unittest.TestCase):
success = False
global topic1
global datatype1
global topic2
global datatype2
topic1=rospy.get_param("/topic1")
datatype1=rospy.get_param('/datatype1')
topic2=rospy.get_param("/topic2")
datatype2=rospy.get_param("/datatype2")

print(topic1,datatype1,topic2,datatype2)
#def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #rospy.loginfo("topic1: %s, datatype1: %s, topic2: %s, datatype2: %s", topic1,  datatype1, topic2, datatype2)
def callback(self,topic1,datatype1,topic2,datatype2):
    # This is the callback function for Group 1 testcase
    #self.rospy.loginfo('topic1 = %s', topic1)
    #self.rospy.loginfo('topic1 = %s', topic2)
    rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id() + "topic1: %s, datatype1: %s, topic2: %s, datatype2: %s",topic1,datatype1,topic2,datatype2)
    self.success = True
def test_WI_group1template(self):
    #This is the python Unit test generic template implementation
    rospy.init_node('WI_group1template', anonymous=True)  
    #rospy.loginfo("topic1: %s, datatype1: %s, topic2: %s, datatype2: %s", topic1,  datatype1, topic2,datatype2 )
    #print("start integration testing node")
    rospy.Subscriber("topic_name", String,self.callback,(topic1, datatype1))
    rospy.Subscriber("topic_name", String, self.callback,(topic2, datatype2))
    timeout_t = time.time() + 5.0
    while (not rospy.is_shutdown() and time.time() < timeout_t and(not self.success)):
        time.sleep(0.1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import rosunit  
    rostest.rosrun(PKG, 'WI_group1template', itn_rtest_group1template)
```

The Launch file looks like this

```
<launch>
 <param name="topic1"  value="chatter"/>
 <param name="datatype1" value="String" />
 <param name="topic2" value="gemoto"/>
 <param name="datatype2" value="String"/>
 <node name="WI_group1template" pkg="itn_rtest" type="int_testtemplate_group1.py" output="screen" 
  clear_params="true"/>   
 <test test-name="WI_XXXX" pkg="itn_rtest" type="int_testtemplate_group1.py" >    </test>  
</launch>
```

My goal is to have one python script, where i can test different communications in a software by simply creating different roslaunch files and pass parameters via the roslaunch files that will be read and used by the python template.

When i run my roslaunch file i get this error log, will be glad if i can get some help concerning this.

`ERROR log "False is not true File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 329, in run testMethod() File "/home/user/integrationtest/src/itn_rtest/test/int_testtemplate_group1.py", line 65, in test_WI_group1template self.assert_(self.success) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 422, in assertTrue raise self.failureException(msg) ------------------------------------------------------------------"`

Answer (score 0):

Decided to seperate the test in different files, reason is because Multiple runs testing different bits of functionality overides values from the parameter server